# create a key value array based on array two values from different array

Tags: php, arrays

I have this array:

```
$priceTableData = array(

    array('productId'=>1,'price'=>50,'discount'=>12),
    array('productId'=>2,'price'=>22,'discount'=>2),
    array('productId'=>3,'price'=>7,'discount'=>0),
    array('productId'=>4,'price'=>9,'discount'=>0),
    array('productId'=>5,'price'=>35,'discount'=>7),

);
```

and I want to get this array out of it:

```
array(5) { 
[1]=> int(12) 
[2]=> int(2) 
[3]=> int(0) 
[4]=> int(0) 
[5]=> int(7) 
}
```

and I used this custom method to do so,

```
function getDiscounts(array $priceData){

    $result = array();

    foreach ($priceData as $array){

        $result[$array['productId']] = $array['discount'];

    }
    return $result;
}
```

then I used it as this:

```
var_dump(getDiscounts($priceTableData));
```

**my question is:** is there a native way of doing so, rather than having a custom function for it?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're using PHP 5.5 you can use [`array_column()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-column.php):

```
 $discounts= array_column($priceTableData , 'discount');
```

[Demo](http://3v4l.org/HSDeb)

Since it was brought up in the comments I will also offer that if your array keys are defined by the product ID you should use the third parameters from array_column() to specify the `productId` as the keys in your new array:

```
$discounts= array_column($priceTableData , 'discount', 'productId ');
```

[Demo](http://3v4l.org/VMsJq)

Comment: what if the id's are not in sequence?

Comment: They didn't specify that was a factor in their desired results. In their specific case as asked in their question this code will serve their purposes.

Comment: `$result[$array['productId']] = $array['discount'];` they are using the id as the key

Comment: thanks I was not aware of such a function, can you tell me where I can find a list of the new functions in 5.5?

Comment: [Here's a list of new features](http://us3.php.net/manual/en/migration55.new-features.php). [Here's a list of new functions](http://us3.php.net/manual/en/migration55.new-functions.php).

Answer (score 2):

you can use [array_column](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-column.php)  which is introduced in PHP 5.5 like so

```
$result = array_column($priceTableData, 'discount','productId');

print_r($result);
```

Answer (score 2):

if older version of php.

```
    $result = array_map(function($sub)
 { return $sub['discount']; }, $priceTableData);
```